# Помогите с перебором DOM-элемента

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, input

При клике нужно чтобы текст со второго input и имя `{item.name}` с `<p>` тега добавлялись в  новый массив с объектами. Формат у объектов `{name: {input.name}, text: input.value}`. При этом таких блоков на странице будет не один, то есть перебрать нужно будет все созданные `div.w-100`.

Понимаю как перебирать значения по одному, но не знаю как так сделать, чтобы в объект записывались значения из каждого `div`

```
<div className='payments_try'>
        <div className='w-100' key={item.id}>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="sameadr"
            />
            <p>{item.name}</p>
            <input
                className='amount_spent'
                type='text'
                placeholder='0'
                key={item.id}
            />
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

все-таки решил сам проблему. Примерно вот такой код:

```
div.forEach((item)=>{
            console.log(`${item.innerText} : ${item.querySelector('.amount_spent').value}`);
        });
```